# Using Nuxt Site as a template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I'm getting started with nuxt, and vue. I want to create a simple site using vue and then turn it into a static site using :

```
nuxt generate
```

I've been able to do this using nuxt and vuetify (you can see this at https://github.com/kc1/nuxt4 ).

Is there a way to use this nuxt project as a template and perform a 'find and replace' with a file to produce an individualized website ?

As an example. The toolbar component is:

```
<template>
  <v-toolbar color="indigo" dark>
    <v-toolbar-side-icon></v-toolbar-side-icon>
    <v-toolbar-title class="white--text">Title</v-toolbar-title>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">
      <v-btn flat>Link One</v-btn>
      <v-btn flat>Link Two</v-btn>
      <v-btn flat>Link Three</v-btn>
    </v-toolbar-items>
  </v-toolbar>
</template>
```

Is there a way to replace:

```
Title - > My project
Link One -> Home
Link Two -> About
Link Three -> Contact
```

Either before or after generating it as a static site?

EDIT:

following the https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store page for nuxt 2.34, In /store/store.js I Placed:

```
export const state = () => ({
'toolbarActions' : [ 'My project', 'Home', 'About', 'Contact' ]
```

})

I'm still getting:

```
ERROR  [Vue warn]: data functions should return an object:                                                                                         20:59:31
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

found in

---> <Menu> at components/menu.vue
    <Default> at layouts/default.vue
        <Root>


ERROR  [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'toolbarActions' in undefined"                              20:59:31

found in

---> <Menu> at components/menu.vue
    <Default> at layouts/default.vue
        <Root>
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT2:

```
<template>
  <v-toolbar color="indigo" dark>
    <v-toolbar-side-icon></v-toolbar-side-icon>
    <v-toolbar-title class="white--text">Title</v-toolbar-title>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">
       <v-btn flat v-for="action in toolbarActions" :key="action">{{action}}</v-btn>
             <!-- <v-btn flat v-for="action in toolbarActions">{{action}}</v-btn> -->
      <!-- <v-btn flat>Link One</v-btn>
      <v-btn flat>Link Two</v-btn>
      <v-btn flat>Link Three</v-btn> -->
    </v-toolbar-items>
  </v-toolbar>
</template>
```

// import toolbarActions from '~/store/store.js'

    export default {
    computed: {
    toolbarActions() {
      return this.$store.getters.loadedPosts
    .....
  


Now I'm seeing:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekB7R.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOeZT.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Vuex to acompplish that.

create a file in store : `/store/store.js`

in there.

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    toolbarActions : [ 'My project', 'Home', 'About', 'Contact' ]
  }
})
```

in your component

```
<template>
...
    <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">
      <v-btn flat v-for="action in toolbarActions">{{action}}</v-btn>
    </v-toolbar-items>
...
</template>

export default {
  computed: {
    toolbarActions() {
      return this.$store.getters.loadedPosts
    }
  }
}
```

This will give you insight of how Vuex works at the beggining.

**Edited**

Use the computed property instead. Let me know.

**Edited 2**

```js
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
  computed: {
    toolbarActions: function() {
      return [ 'My project', 'Home', 'About', 'Contact' ]
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.21/dist/vue.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.0.1/vuex.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/1.3.15/vuetify.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/1.3.15/vuetify.css" />
     
     <div id="app">
     <v-toolbar color="indigo" dark>
        <v-toolbar-side-icon></v-toolbar-side-icon>
        <v-toolbar-title class="white--text">Title</v-toolbar-title>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">
           <v-btn flat v-for="action in toolbarActions" :key="action">{{action}}</v-btn>
                 <!-- <v-btn flat v-for="action in toolbarActions">{{action}}</v-btn> -->
          <!-- <v-btn flat>Link One</v-btn>
          <v-btn flat>Link Two</v-btn>
          <v-btn flat>Link Three</v-btn> -->
        </v-toolbar-items>
      </v-toolbar>
     </div>
```

**P.D.:** `<v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">` are hidden the buttons in small devices.

Once clicked on run snippet, click in fullpage to see it working.

Comment: Bloody hell, this part of code is totally against all rules in documentation. Dont ever do this!  `data: function() {
      toolbarActions: this.$store.toolbarActions
   }`

Comment: I'm running into a number of errors including ' Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'toolbarActions' in undefined '. Taking a look at https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store, I'm assuming that the problem is with the vux store. I tried changing to the edit above.

Comment: @webmint i fix it by using computed property. This is more suitable for this escenario.

Comment: @Yoarthur Yes, and also what is better to use mapGetters vuex helper.

Comment: its not really working , but please take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/r8d470j5/1/

Comment: in the html, import via CDN the libs you're using. using the normal `<link>` tag or `<script>`

Comment: Thanks, that does work! I'll need to play with it to try to figure out how to get the vuex store working.

Answer (score 2):

Read about ENV variables.

Also i would suggest u to create js file with values, add there export and use this file variables in nuxt components.

Another variant could be using Vuex store. U can create there for example module mainMeny and define there number of links, titles, and urls.